# Interpreting dichotomous independent variable in two-way fixed effects models

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Good evening,

Apologies if the question has been answered, but I did search through the archive and did not find something similar to my question.

I am curious if I am interpreting a categorical variable. In my data, I have two categorical variables that varies between 0 and 1 in each panel and indicates "1" when there's a trade agreement from the exporter or importer in place between two countries in some years and "0" when there is not in other years.

```
| year | ExpAg   | ImpAg   | pair | Value26  |
|------|---------|---------|------|----------|
| 1995 |       0 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 1996 |       0 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 1997 |       0 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 1998 |       0 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 1999 |       0 |       0 | 1734 |    2.011 |
| 2000 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2001 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |    1.058 |
| 2002 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2003 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2004 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2005 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2006 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2007 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2008 |       1 |       0 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2009 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2010 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2011 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2012 |       1 |       1 | 1734 | 156.2506 |
| 2013 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |   365.49 |
| 2014 |       1 |       1 | 1734 | 330.2503 |
| 2015 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |   66.946 |
| 2016 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |  326.022 |
| 2017 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |        0 |
| 2018 |       1 |       1 | 1734 |  238.726 |
```

I am curious as to how I interpret the coefficients in a two-way fixed effects model. I was taught that in time series cross-sectional data, the interpretation of the coefficients is that when X varies across time by one unit, Y increases or decreases" some value of the coefficient.

How would I interpret the categorical variable since it might have 4 or 5 years as 0, then change to 1 for the remainder of the years of the panel? Do I ignore the "across time" aspect?

Comment: Is your question specifically how to interpret `ExpAg` and `ImpAg` independently? Do the variables change over time *within* each panel unit? Also, what does `pair` denote?

Comment: @ThomasBilach, `pair` refers to the dyad of the exporter and importer. Pair 1734 is just one of several thousand in the data set. `ExpAg` and `ImpAg` change over time once, from 0 to 1 in each of the panels but at different points in time, depending on the countries. `ExpAg` and `ImpAg` are not in the model together, but are different treatments that are evaluated separately.